# Regex extract string without last char parameter

Tags: php, regex

Does anyone know what the regex to get the following result:

```
Hello world, Another day to die. => Hello world
```

I'm trying the following expression:

```
/^.*,/
```

But the result is 'Hello world!'

I want to ignore the last character (!). Can anyone give me a hand?

Best regards.

Comment: I didn't see any `!`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
/^.*?(?=,)/
```

Example use:

```
preg_match('/^.*?(?=,)/', "Hello world, Another day to die.", $matches);
echo "Found: {$matches[0]}\n";
```

Output:

```
Found: Hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with @acdcjunior's answer, here are a few alternatives:

```
"/^.*?(?=,)/" // (full match)
"/^(.*?),/"  // (get element 1 from result array)
"/^[^,]+/"  // (full match, bonus points for matching full string if there is no comma)
explode(",",$input)[0] // PHP 5.4 or newer
array_shift(explode(",",$input)) // PHP 5.3 and older
substr($input,0,strpos($input,","))
```

There are many ways to achieve this ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is another one,

```
$str = 'Hello world, Another day to die';
preg_match('/[^,]+/', $str, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

```
/^[\w\s]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, that only checks letters:

```
/^[a-z]+ [a-z]+/i
```

or without regex:

```
$res = split(",", $string, 2)[0];
```